# Why such a discrepancy on location of Abydos between Stargate the movie and SG1 the series?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Other than the obvious "retcon!!11!" reason, was there ever an in-universe explanation about the obvious mistake the scientists made about where Abydos was actually located?

In the movie it is said that the planet is "...in another galaxy, on the other side of the observable universe."  In the series it turns out that not only is Abydos in our own galaxy, but it's in fact the *closest* planet to Earth with a stargate on it that can still be dialed without a DHD accounting for the stellar drift.  The writers went out of their way to explain other small inconsistencies (Ra being not "last" of his kind, but "oldest", etc.) but not this huge glaring error.

Comment: Because retcon,  that's why.

Comment: So they didn't even bother explaining it away?  Like "Oops, my bad, I missed a decimal point over there."

Comment: No reason was ever given (heck, other than the film there's never even any reference to the whole "other side of the universe thing"!), but if we want to wildly speculate -- simply getting it wrong is awful plausible (I mean, really, how could a simple probe inside a pyramid know where it was in relation to the observable universe anyway?)!

Comment: Agreed with the VTC.  I guess I didn't search hard enough :)

Comment: @Chahk "[Well that'd be fine.  O'Neill.  Two 'L's!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzJEkOCO1jo)" - there were some hints that what happened in the movie was not _quite_ what happened on Abydos in the TV-canon, but that it was rather close ([movie Jack only had 1 "L"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_(film)#Cast_and_characters)).  The location of the planet would simply have been another one of those discrepancies.

Comment: How about "Accuracy"? You try navigating by constellations outside of our own galaxy and we'll see how well that goes. Of course, those constellations don't even exist outside of a 300-light-year bubble around earth, *but still!*

Comment: The out-of-universe reason was simple pragmatism. The movie made no scientific sense, and didn't give much information. Was there even more than one stargate, for instance? We don't know. The show introduced a ton of ideas, like the Stargate network itself, rather than just one, and tried to come up with some consistency for the system, and also with some limitations.

If your heroes can go anywhere in the universe, that's too big, or so producers thought. A galaxy is more limited and better, they thought. It's much the same thinking that changed the speed of warp drive between TOS and TNG